# Проблема с вызовом функции, выводит от переданного значения до начала

Tags: python, функции, kivy

Хочу менять источник изображения при каждом нажатии кнопки вперёд, но почему-то выводит поочерёдно от переданного значения до самого начала.
Вот часть кода, отвечающая за это:

```
    def update_button(image_text):
        print(image_text)
        a = ["image0.png", "image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png", "image6.png", "image7.png", "image8.png", "image9.png", "image10.png", "image11.png", "image12.png"]
        j = a.index(image_text)
        print(j)
        if j == 13:
            j = 0
        buttonnext_text.unbind(on_press=lambda b=a[j]: Next(a[j]))
        buttonprev_text.unbind(on_press=lambda b=a[j - 1]: prev(a[j - 1]))
        buttonnext_text.bind(on_press=lambda b=a[j + 1]: Next(a[j + 1]))
        buttonprev_text.bind(on_press=lambda b=a[j]: prev(a[j]))

    def Next(b):
        image.source = b
        update_button(b)
    def prev(b):
        print(b)
```

Позже заменю `pirnt(b)` на нужный мне код. Заранее спасибо большое всем за помощь))

Comment: Какая-то у вас странная форма описания `lambda`, первый раз такое вижу в аргументах

Comment: Если использовать без описания, то будет выдавать ошибку. А если брать переменную b, то выводится не то, что мне нужно

Comment: Всё, я уже сам нашёл свою ошибку